# I would like to use the return value of a function in another function, without running through that function again. (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, return, return-value

Right now every time I use cost = get_cost(), for instance, the function goes through and asks for an input again. Is there a way to have just the return value be what is saved, so I can use that value in another function? Thanks for all the help.

```
def get_cost():

    cost = float(input('Please Enter the Cost of the Meal: '))

    while cost <= 0:
        print('The Cost Must Be Greater Than 0!')
        cost = float(input('Please Enter the Cost of the Meal: '))
    else:
        return cost

def compute_tip():

    cost = get_cost()

    finalTip = cost * 0.18
    return finalTip

def compute_tax():

    cost = get_cost()

    finalTax = cost * 0.0825
    return finalTax

def compute_grand_total():

    cost = get_cost()    
    finalTip = compute_tip()
    finalTax = compute_tax()

    grandTotal = cost + finalTip + finalTax
    return grandTotal

def display_total_cost():

    cost = get_cost()
    finalTip = compute_tip()
    finalTax = compute_tax()
    grandTotal = compute_grand_total()

    print('Cost\t$', format(cost, '.2f'))
    print('Tip\t$', format(finalTip, '.2f'))
    print('Tax\t$', format(finalTax, '.2f'))
    print('Total\t$', format(grandTotal, '.2f'))


def main():

    get_cost()

    compute_tip()

    compute_tax()

    compute_grand_total()

    display_total_cost()

main()
```

Comment: You might want to consider passing the `cost` to the functions that need it so you don't need to call the `get_cost()` function again and again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it looks like your main function only needs to include the one function call

```py
def main():
    display_total_cost()
```

because `display_total_cost()` internally calls all your other functions as needed.

then you can pass `cost` as a function parameter to the other functions that require it and remove the `get_cost` calls from all the other functions. Here is an updated version of your script:

```py
def get_cost():

    cost = float(input('Please Enter the Cost of the Meal: '))

    while cost <= 0:
        print('The Cost Must Be Greater Than 0!')
        cost = float(input('Please Enter the Cost of the Meal: '))
    else:
        return cost

def compute_tip(cost):
    finalTip = cost * 0.18
    return finalTip

def compute_tax(cost):
    finalTax = cost * 0.0825
    return finalTax

def display_total_cost():

    cost = get_cost()
    finalTip = compute_tip(cost)
    finalTax = compute_tax(cost)
    grandTotal = cost + finalTip + finalTax

    print('Cost\t$', format(cost, '.2f'))
    print('Tip\t$', format(finalTip, '.2f'))
    print('Tax\t$', format(finalTax, '.2f'))
    print('Total\t$', format(grandTotal, '.2f'))


def main():
    display_total_cost()

# common practice is to include this line
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks, your explanation was concise and thorough

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the value once its returned, and pass it to the other functions. Something like this:

```
def main():
    cost = get_cost()
    tip = compute_tip(cost)
    tax = compute_tax(cost)
    total = compute_grand_total(tip, tax)
    display_total_cost(total)
```

But you would also have to rewrite the functions to accept these arguments, for example:

```
def compute_tip(cost):
    finalTip = cost * 0.18
    return finalTip
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in parameters, so you don't need to keep calling the same functions.

```
    def get_cost():

    cost = float(input('Please Enter the Cost of the Meal: '))

    while cost <= 0:
        print('The Cost Must Be Greater Than 0!')
        cost = float(input('Please Enter the Cost of the Meal: '))
    else:
        return cost

def compute_tip(cost):

    finalTip = cost * 0.18
    return finalTip

def compute_tax(cost):

    finalTax = cost * 0.0825
    return finalTax

def compute_grand_total(cost, finalTip, finalTax):

    grandTotal = cost + finalTip + finalTax
    return grandTotal

def display_total_cost(cost):

    finalTip = compute_tip(cost)
    finalTax = compute_tax(cost)
    grandTotal = compute_grand_total(cost, finalTip, finalTax)

    print('Cost\t$', format(cost, '.2f'))
    print('Tip\t$', format(finalTip, '.2f'))
    print('Tax\t$', format(finalTax, '.2f'))
    print('Total\t$', format(grandTotal, '.2f'))

def main():

    cost = get_cost()

    display_total_cost(cost)

main()
```